# I wrote a program using Drag and Drop in java, I need few updation in this. Can anyone help me please?

Tags: swing

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class scjp extends TransferHandler
{
JTextField txtField;
JRadioButton lbl=new JRadioButton("Hello");
public static void main(String[] args)
{
scjp sdd = new scjp();
transfer th=new transfer(); 

}

public scjp()
{

MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter()
{
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
JComponent jc = (JComponent)e.getSource();
TransferHandler th = jc.getTransferHandler();
th.exportAsDrag(jc, e, TransferHandler.COPY);
}   
};
MouseMotionListener m2=new MouseAdapter()
{
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
{

}
};
JFrame frame = new JFrame("SCJP");
txtField = new JTextField(20);
lbl.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("text"));
lbl.addMouseListener(ml);
lbl.addMouseMotionListener(m2);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(txtField);
frame.add(lbl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.setSize(400, 400);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EX…
frame.setResizable(false);
} 
}
```

here i m dragging a radio and dropping that into a textBox, when i m dragging the radio button, my mouse pointer looks like (a rectangle and plus sign below the arrow).

What i need to do:

when i pick/drag the radio that time instead of that rectangle and plus sign, i want that string which is of radio??
i mean to say the radio button string/text i want as with my mouse cursor upto i drop that component/radio in text box..?
please help me to figure out this problem as soon as possible, please.

Answer (score 0):

First look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942916/how-to-change-cursor-when-dropping-into-java-application) - this explains how to change the cursor while performing drag n drop.
Once you understand the concept, you will have to code a method that creates an in-memory image of text from the radio button in question. That image can be used in populating the cursor.

Pseudo code:

```
img = //in-memory image created by writing text of radio button to graphics.
Cursor curCircle = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(img,new Point(5,5),"some text");
```

Set the new cursor in `dragEnter` - and then take care of `dragExit` to restore original cursor.